# SQL Find rows with missing columns based on another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle, postgresql-11, oracle19c

I have a scenario in which I need to use a table of valid elements to find records in another table which are missing those elements so that I can in turn patch them in.  It's a bit trickier because the missing column data is in a "nested" column (e.g. it has repeating entries in another column).  I feel like some kind of LEFT OUTER JOIN may be at play here, but I can't quite get it straight.  FWIW, my baseline is Oracle 19c, but I need to eventually support Postgres 11+ as well.  The problem is summarized as:

Given a table of tenants:

| Tenant |
| --- |
| 1000 |
| 2000 |
| 3000 |

And a table of groups, wherein each day corresponds to a new group id and each group has 1-to-many tenants, where each tenent corresponds to a subgroup id:

| Date | Group | Tenant | Subgroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-16 | G1 | 1000 | SG1 |
| 2021-02-16 | G1 | 2000 | SG2 |
| 2021-02-16 | G1 | 3000 | SG3 |
| 2021-02-17 | G2 | 1000 | SG4 |
| 2021-02-17 | G2 | 2000 | SG5 |
| 2021-02-18 | G3 | 2000 | SG6 |
| 2021-02-18 | G3 | 3000 | SG7 |
| 2021-02-19 | G4 | 1000 | SG8 |

Find the groups that are missing tenants:

| Group | Tenant |
| --- | --- |
| G2 | 3000 |
| G3 | 1000 |
| G4 | 2000 |
| G4 | 3000 |

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH
   tab1 AS
      ( SELECT TO_DATE('16.02.2021', 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS date_col, 'G1' AS group_col, 1000 AS tenant, 'SG1' AS subgroup FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TO_DATE('16.02.2021', 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS date_col, 'G1' AS group_col, 2000 AS tenant, 'SG2' AS subgroup FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TO_DATE('16.02.2021', 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS date_col, 'G1' AS group_col, 3000 AS tenant, 'SG3' AS subgroup FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TO_DATE('17.02.2021', 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS date_col, 'G2' AS group_col, 1000 AS tenant, 'SG4' AS subgroup FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TO_DATE('17.02.2021', 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS date_col, 'G2' AS group_col, 2000 AS tenant, 'SG5' AS subgroup FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TO_DATE('18.02.2021', 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS date_col, 'G3' AS group_col, 2000 AS tenant, 'SG6' AS subgroup FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TO_DATE('18.02.2021', 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS date_col, 'G3' AS group_col, 3000 AS tenant, 'SG7' AS subgroup FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TO_DATE('19.02.2021', 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS date_col, 'G4' AS group_col, 1000 AS tenant, 'SG8' AS subgroup FROM DUAL
      ),
   tab2 AS
      ( SELECT 1000 AS tenant FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2000 AS tenant FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3000 AS tenant FROM DUAL
      )
SELECT *
  FROM ( SELECT t1.group_col,
                t2.tenant
           FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT group_col FROM tab1) t1
           CROSS JOIN tab2 t2
       ) x
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                      FROM tab1
                     WHERE tab1.group_col = x.group_col
                       AND tab1.tenant = x.tenant
                  )
  ORDER BY group_col,
           tenant;
```

Result:

```
GR     TENANT
-- ----------
G2       3000
G3       1000
G4       2000
G4       3000
```

The query works also in Postgres (then remove `FROM DUAL` or you will adapt it to your tables).

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you could use [partitioned outer join](https://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/270646.htm) so that you fill in the missing rows and then you can select just these

```
select g.group_col, t.tenant
  from groups g partition by (group_col)
 right outer join tenants t on t.tenant = g.tenant
 where g.tenant is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I approach this by using `cross join` to generate all the rows and then remove the ones that exist.  The following is standard SQL and works in both Oracle and Postgres:

```
select g.group_id, t.tenant
from tenants t cross join
     (select distinct group_id from groups) g left join
     groups g2
     using (tenant, group_id)
where g2.tenant is null;
```